# Resetting a column excel report

Tags: c#, excel, reporting

I am trying create an excel report from my code, basically when i get to the second if statement, the data goes to different columns to that off the first one, basically it starts in column B, this should be always the starting Column, how do i do this ?

```
arrData = clsData.GetReport(strStartDate, strEndDate);

dataCount = arrData.Count;
string col = "B";

foreach (string item in arrData)
{
    string[] stuff = item.Split('\t');


    if (stuff[0].Equals("Machine1"))
    {
         if (stuff[5].Equals("M")) 
         {
            row = 5;
            ws.Cells[row, col] = stuff[1];                   // Morning Shift Total 
            col = IncCol(col);
         }
    }
    else 
    {
         if (stuff[5].Equals("N")) 
         {
            row = 6;
            ws.Cells[row, col] = stuff[1];                   //Night Shift Total 
            col = IncCol(col);
         }
    }


    if (stuff[0].Equals("Machine2"))
    {
        if (stuff[5].Equals("M"))
        {
            row = 10;
             ws.Cells[row, col] = stuff[1];                   //Morning Shift Total 
            col = IncCol(col);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (stuff[5].Equals("N"))
        {
            row = 11;
            ws.Cells[row, col] = stuff[1];                   //Night Shift Total 
            col = IncCol(col);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking, from your code you seem to understand what to do. Are you using an Excel Library to generate the report?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: yes... you can see from the two if statements i have a morning and night shift, i need these to go in column B-5 and the other in B-6 within the excel sheet, but at the minute its not, its going to the next available column

Answer (score 0):

your `else` part for the night/morning shift should be within the `if` condition for the `Machine1/Machine2`

```
arrData = clsData.GetReport(strStartDate, strEndDate);

dataCount = arrData.Count;
string col = "B";

foreach (string item in arrData)
{
    string[] stuff = item.Split('\t');
    if (stuff[0].Equals("Machine1"))
    {
        if (stuff[5].Equals("M")) 
        {
            row = 5;
            ws.Cells[row, col] = stuff[1];                   // Morning Shift Total 
            col = IncCol(col);
        }
        else 
        {
            if (stuff[5].Equals("N")) 
            {
                row = 6;
                ws.Cells[row, col] = stuff[1];               //Night Shift Total 
                col = IncCol(col);
            }
        }
    }              
    else 
    {
        if (stuff[0].Equals("Machine2"))
        {
            if (stuff[5].Equals("M"))
            {
                row = 10;
                ws.Cells[row, col] = stuff[1];               //Morning Shift Total 
                col = IncCol(col);
            }
            else
            {
                if (stuff[5].Equals("N"))
                {
                    row = 11;
                    ws.Cells[row, col] = stuff[1];           //Night Shift Total 
                    col = IncCol(col);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```